# R Markdown (Pandoc) beamer presentation with short title

Tags: yaml, latex, r-markdown, pandoc, beamer

I am trying to use `beamer_presentation` in RMarkdown and in the YAML header I include, say, `title: "Long title"`. This title appears on the first title page of my slides but also at the bottom of all slides. However, at the bottom of all slides I would like a shorter title to appear. I wonder if something like `short-title: "Short title"` could be used. I know that there is `uiucthemes` that allows that, but I don't want to use the uiuc style.
Thanks!

Comment: You'd probably have to use a custom template, see http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#templates

Answer (score 13):

You can pass an optional argument to the `\title` macro which will be used in the footline:

```
---
title: "Long title"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: "CambridgeUS"
    keep_tex: true
header-includes:
  - \AtBeginDocument{\title[short title for footline]{long title for title page}}

---



text
```

[image]